# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while changing the dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to replace 'cmd' key inside the d1 dictionary with `d2['cmd']`.

```
d1 = {'db1': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases ', 'request': 'POST'}], 'db2': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases ', 'request': 'POST'}]}

d2 = {'cmd': 'test'}
{k: d2.get(v, v) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

My code is throwing this error :

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while changing the dictionary values.

Comment: `d2.get(v,v)` => `d2.get(k, v)`

Comment: but `d1['cmd']` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested dictionary comprehension here. Or alternative as in this case, a dictionary comprehension with a further unpacking into a dictionary. As per [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you can merge dictionaries with the syntax shown bellow, where the later values will always override earlier ones:

```
{k1:{**v1[0], **d2} for k1,v1 in d1.items()}

{'db1': {'cmd': 'test', 'request': 'POST', 'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api'},
 'db2': {'cmd': 'test', 'request': 'POST', 'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api'}}
```

Comment: Should be `{k1:[{**v1[0], **d2}] for k1,v1 in d1.items()}`, note the items are actually lists containing one dictionary.  A more straightforward solution is to modify the mapping in place with an update for the inner mappings, unless the original mapping is needed.

Comment: Yes to preserve the initial structure yes. Didn't do so though as I can't see the sense in having a single dictionary contained in a list @metatoaster

Comment: what is  **v1[0] and **d2. I know its merging of 2 dictionary

Comment: Updated with some more info @Mous

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you could do like this, it's easy and readable.

```py
for k, v in d1.items():
    v[0].update(d2)
```